# Value of $\int_0^33x^2f(x^3)dx$ given $\int_{0}^{9}f(x)dx=4$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given f is continuous and $\int_{0}^{9}f(x)dx=4$, find the value of $\int_0^33x^2f(x^3)dx$

The first thing I did was let $u=x^3$. Then
$du=3x^2dx$ and then $dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du$.This gives me $$\int_0^{27}f(u)du$$

but at this point I'm not sure how to finish the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised that the person who made the exercise had in mind $\int_0^3 2xf(x^2)dx$. Because as written you can't conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what is said in the comments:
$$\int_0^{27}f(u)du = \int_0^9f(u)du + \int_9^{27}f(u)du = 4 + \int_9^{27}f(u)du$$
You can't conclude anything from this point as $f(x)$ is not specified.

Just as an example, $f(x) = \frac{4}{9}$ and $f(x) = x - 4.056$ both have $\int_0^9 f(x)dx$ as 4, but $\int_9^{27} f(x) dx$ varies for both of these functions.